# MS Access - Combine Data from Multiple Records into Single Record

Tags: ms-access, merge, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint list which allows users from various teams across my organization to submit their level of impact for a given project. The list is configured so that each teams' level of impact is captured in their own individual column. Because of how I configured this, I have multiple rows in my data for the same project, with each containing only one impact value in the column for the team that submitted the record. I would like to combine all of the records for each project into one consolidated row that contains the impact from each teams' submission. For example:

**The data as it is collected and displayed from the SharePoint list:
**

[image: Data from SharePoint List]

**Desired end result with merged records:
**

[image: End Result]

Should this be done with a Access Query or a new table that joins the data somehow?

Thank you!

I have tried searching online for a solution, but most provide directions for concatenating values into a single column instead of merging multiple rows into one record.

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text tables, not images.

Comment: You can also try running the Crosstab query wizard on your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output should be possible with a simple aggregate query using Max() function.

```
SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, Max(JanitorStaffImpact) AS MJSI,
Max(PaintingTeamImpact) AS MPTI, Max(ManagementTeamImpact) AS MMTI
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ProjectID, ProjectName;
```

As suggested in a comment, can also be done by a CROSSTAB.

```
TRANSFORM First(Nz([JanitorStaffImpact],Nz([PaintingTeamImpact],[ManagementTeamImpact]))) AS D
SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ProjectID, ProjectName
PIVOT Sub & " Impact" IN("Janitor Staff Impact", "Painting Team Impact", "Management Team Impact";
```

A third approach suggested in another answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - This is the solution I was looking for and I have marked your reply as accepted. 

Quick follow up - Is there any way for me to return the column headers with spaces in them without showing the double quotes. For example, if I want to return a column as "Janitor Staff Impact" in the column header, can I do so without the quotes?

Comment: Why would there be quotes? If you want spaces in field name, enclose in brackets. But why? Can do whatever you want in label on report. I always advise not to design with spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be written using `joined query` :

```
SELECT A.ProjectID , A.ProjectName , A.TeamA , B.TeamB, C.TeamC  
FROM (
           (SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE Submitter="Team A") AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE Submitter="Team B") AS B ON A.ProjectID=B.ProjectID)
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE Submitter="Team C") AS C ON A.ProjectID=C.ProjectID
```